# Hazelcast MapStore and JPA Repository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, hazelcast

Since many days, I try to make an Hazelcast MapStore works with a JPARepository but I cannot make it working because I cannot create a transaction:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

I know that the MapStore does not participate to the Spring transaction as stated in the documentation but I would like to explicitly create another one if needed. I tried with `TransactionTemplate` or `PlateformTransactioManager` but it seems that it has no effect:

```
  @Autowired
  private UuidSpringDataJpaRepository uuidSpringDataJpaRepository;
  @Autowired
  private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

...

  @Override
  public void storeAll(Map<String, V> map) {
    LOGGER.info("[{}, {}] storeAll: {}", tenant, cacheType, map);
    ClientDatabaseContextHolder.setTenantName(tenant);
    try {
      TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
      txTemplate.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
      txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
        @Override
        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
          for (Entry<String, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            storeUuidEntity(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
          }
          uuidSpringDataJpaRepository.flush();
        }
      });
    } finally {
      ClientDatabaseContextHolder.removeTenantName();
    }
  }
```

I saw already some exemples like [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-data-integration/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spring/jpa/JPAMapStore.java) so this might be feasible I guess ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jerome, you can actually let MapStore participate into Spring Transaction. Use `@Transactional` annotation on `UuidSpringDataJpaRepository` or another Service and/or any related method and call that method.